# How to redirect to another page in Office JS

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have a control with action - ExecuteFunction in Outlook addin.

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="button1">
                  <Label resid="buttonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="buttonTitle" />
                    <Description resid="buttonSuperTipDescr" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>redirectFunction</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
```

And in the corresponding js, I have a function which needs to redirect to another page like below.

```
function redirectFunction() {
                    window.open("https://othersite.com")
                    //window.location.href = "https://othersite.com";
                }
```

I have added the othersite.com in the App Domains List in the manifest file. Still I am unable to redirect to another page.

Do we need to include anything else ? How can we redirect to another page directly on click of the button ?

Comment: Do you own the other site that you're attempting to redirect? Is it a frame-able site?

Comment: An executeFunction happens to be an action without any UI. Is there a specific reason for you to use executeFunction and redirect? May we understand the use case better to assist you?

Comment: HI Mavi , No the site is not frame-able.

Comment: Hi @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT , I am trying to redirect the user to a Yammer page. If I open a taskpane and put an achor tag I am able to re-direct to Yammer Page. Can't we directly redirect from the button click. It still executes the function. its not just redirecting. Any way we could achieve this ?

Comment: @AhmedVali - Can you please clarify what do you mean? Are you using the function capability and not the taskpane? When you say you're redirecting are you talking about opening a new browser window and redirecting to the page?

Comment: @Mavi, Currently i have a button which executes a function in Outlook addin. Inside this function, I am trying to open a another site in new window and it is not working. I am using window.location.href and pointing it to target url.

Comment: @AhmedVali - functions are UIless though? So you wouldn't have a UI for function?

Comment: @Mavi , Thank you for your responses. What i am looking into is-  on click of the button, the function is called and it is getting executed (have printed console logs and verified isnide function), but it is not redirecting to the page. My question is will the redirection work at all ? If I execute window.location.href inside any function, will it take me to the target page ?

Comment: It won't - because that javascript is not running in a page (strictly speaking) - it's UI'less - you can put some random tags into your function.html and you can't ever see them. The only use for the function endpoint is really executing the function (communicating with the office client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned you are using the `functions`.

If you are referring to the `FunctionFile` which is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile) - that experience doesn't have any User Interface associated with it. All it can do is execute a JavaScript function on a button click. **So nothing that you put on the function file or endpoint (doesn't matter if it's an html file or a server rendered page) will ever be displayed to the user.**

If you want to display Yammer to the user as a result of the button click or some action, try doing `window.open('https://yammer.com')`. This should work if the domain is whitelisted in your manifest.

Comment: Hi Mavi, Yes, I though window.ope() would work. But it isn't. See my configuration below.

Comment: Hi Mavi, Yes, I thought window.open() would do the trick. But it isn't. I have edited the question with the code. It is not working with the above configuration.

Comment: To clarify - what are you exactly trying to achieve - Are you openeing a task pane with some url in it and then clicking the UI less button expecting the url in taskpane to change to the new one? window .open() will open a new default browser(based on you settings) with the url you mention. If that's not what you are seeing, could you share the errors you are seeing when this happens?